# Changing GtkScale trough color in GTK+3

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I've got a GtkScale in my application for which I'm trying to change the color of the trough.

I've tried the following CSS to no avail:

```
.scale.trough {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the latest Gtk+ version, try with:

```
scale trough {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

As seen in these images (Fedora 28):
[image]

Comment: That works! Can you provide some insight into how you figured that out? I tried matching my syntax to the CSS node layout provided [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkScale.html)

Comment: @cradical Typically, I use [Gtk Inspector](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK%2B/Inspector) to try out CSS tweaks. Looking to the docs, you have the css nodes in use by GtkScale as referenced.

Comment: This wasn't doing anything for me until I also added `background-image: none`. Anyone else having this issue, try that.

Comment: @Rena It may have changed in Gtk4. Haven't tried it.